Remix Defer/Suspense/Await does not show loading fallback
I have created a new Remix application where I defer a promise in the loader :
// Index.tsx
import { defer } from "@remix-run/node";
import { Await, useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import DataFetchingExample from "~/components/data-fetching";
import Loading from "~/components/Loading";

export function loader() {
  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, Number(4000)));
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos",
      {
        // disable cache
        cache: "no-store",
      }
    );

    if (!response || response.status !== 200) {
      console.error("Failed to fetch data");
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    const post = data[0];
    return post;
  };

  const promiseRequest = fetchPosts();

  return defer({
    post: promiseRequest,
  });
}

export default function Index() {
  const data = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to Remix</h1>

      <Suspense fallback={<Skeleton />}>
        <Await resolve={data.post} errorElement={<p>Could not fetch photos</p>}>
          {(post) => <DataFetchingExample post={post} />}
        </Await>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}

// components/data-fetching.tsx
type PageProps = {
  post: {
    albumId: number,
    id: number,
    title: string,
    url: string,
    thumbnailUrl: string,
  },
};

export default function DataFetchingExample({ post }: PageProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Todo: {post?.title}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

I expect to see the skeleton from <Suspense> but it is not showing up when the page is loading...
Instead, the page remains frozen until I receive the promise :(
Is this supposed to work like this or am I misunderstanding something?
What am I doing wrong?
I want to see the loading skeleton until I receive the data to see the results, can you help me?

I tried your code in a sandbox and it seems to function as you are expecting. Do you have any errors in the console or any additional debugging information? Can you try creating a running codesandbox of your own that reproduces the issue you describe that we could inspect live?

Ok found! this is due to slow 3G connection mode in the developper tools window. Unbelievable!! This code works as expected. Thanks.
